# Can two different processes on a two cpu machine access same RAM address simultaneously

Tags: operating-system

If I have a computer with two cpu's which run a process each, they both want to take place on the run with the same virtual address 'x'. Could that happen that they get the same place in the physical address space? (Because they are simultaneous, and don't know that the other asked for space too and could accidentally get same physical address)

Comment: I'd certainly hope not. It's very unlikely unless there was a serious bug in the kernel.

Comment: Are you writing OS-level code, or application-level? If it's the latter, you shouldn't need to worry about this.

Comment: That is an OS theoretical question. I am talking in a modern OS, like windows 7, ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are memory primitives which allow atomic access to memory. This allows multiple cpus to coordinate. Without this sort of primitive, two cpus would not have the ability to coordinate their efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Allocation of address spaces is coordinated so that two processes do not share part of their address space by chance. The OS might share between processes read only portions of their address spaces, the typical example being the program itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'No'.  There are mechanisms that prevent it.

http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece548/handouts/19coher.pdf has some nice slides that address the topic at a relatively high level - but the accompanying text would probably be more insightful.